# How can I fix too many redirects caused by .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I recently added a Wordpress blog to a client's website. I create a subdirectory and installed Wordpress there. Everything worked fine until I added a .htaccess file to the root directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^websitename.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.websitename.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Now, when I click on the blog link I get the following error

```
The webpage at http://websitename.com/blog/ has resulted in too many redirects. 
Clearing    your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with 
your computer.
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem? I'm not at all familiar with .htaccess.

Edit: Just to be clear, The 301 redirect works fine for all of the pages, Except for the blog folder. If you type in websitename.com, your redirected to www.websitename.com. However if you type in websitename.com/blog you will encounter the error. The blog in in this example points to a Wordpress folder.

Answer (score 6):

I take it you are trying to force "www."?

Use the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^suncoastlaw\.com
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

To get a little bit more info, check out the post I wrote here: [Forcing www](http://nishantk.net/wordpress/?p=95)

Answer (score 4):

you want `*.suncoastlaw.com/xx -> www.suncoastlaw.com/xx` do you ?

then your conf

`^(.*)$ http://www.suncoastlaw.com/$1`

let www.suncoastlaw.com/$1 301-> www.suncoastlaw.com/$1

so there would be too many redirect

change to

`rewritecond %{http_host} !www.suncoastlaw.com`

when not www.suncoastlaw.com then redirect

all the rewrite conf detail could be found at

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

**how to trace**

your http://suncoastlaw.com/blog/ redirect to http://www.suncoastlaw.com/blog/ and then
http://www.suncoastlaw.com/blog/ redirect to http://suncoastlaw.com/blog/
this is the problem

```
$ curl -I http://suncoastlaw.com/blog/
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 26 Jan 2013 13:37:10 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.suncoastlaw.com/blog/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1



$ curl -I http://www.suncoastlaw.com/blog/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sat, 26 Jan 2013 13:37:21 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Pingback: http://suncoastlaw.com/blog/xmlrpc.php
Location: http://suncoastlaw.com/blog/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: If I used this approach, would I still want to leave the [nc] at the end of the second line?

Comment: @MikeTheCoder [nc] means [no case] add if you want

Comment: The suggestion on how to trace the issue was helpful to narrow down the problem for me. In my case, the problem stemmed from html5-boilerplate library, which contains .htaccess file in its dist folder.  This file redirects www.hostname.com to hostname.com by default, which clashed with the opposite rule specified in our site's root .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these lines to your httpd.conf file instead of using .htaccess file to force WWW sub-domain:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(127\.0\.0\.0|localhost) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [L,R=301]
```

You might also want to add your IP in the list of the second line, if you'll be accessing your web server by IP only. For a bit more explanation also read the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823038/mod-rewrite-too-many-redirects-problem) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Problem Soved. I, unfortunately was not able to figure it out, but I got someone that could. The problem, apparently, was due to the fact that in my database, the site was without WWW. So my blog redirected to my old site's URL. The problem was fixed by adding WWW.

Comment: This was my problem too. If it's a WordPress site, make sure the URLs in Settings > General are wanted format, or else your redirect code will battle with WordPress's redirection and cause the infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem was not the rule. The rule was correct but the order of the rules in the .htaccess was not. This is what I had before. Note I am rewriting to non-www.

```
  #https
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  #remove home
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/home
  RewriteRule ^(.*)home$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 


 # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
 #  slashes.
 # If your page resides at
 #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
 # then use
 # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
 #RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

 #301 redirect
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I changed to

```
 #301 redirect
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

 #https
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  #remove home
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/home
  RewriteRule ^(.*)home$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 


 # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
 #  slashes.
 # If your page resides at
 #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
 # then use
 # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
 #RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^websitename.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.websitename.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

Replace

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}