# ModRewrite causing Duplicate Title errors in Webmaster Tools

Tags: php, .htaccess

I use rewrite rules to redirect server.php to a more seo-friendly link. However webmaster tools is reporting that I have hundreds of duplicate title errors.. it looks like Google is indexing both the server.php and seo-friendly versions. Any idea how to fix this?

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^minecraftserverfinder.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.minecraftserverfinder.com/$1 [r=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(.*)$ server.php?s=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: maybe duplicated question  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533641/how-can-i-fix-too-many-redirects-caused-by-htaccess/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what you're suggesting is impossible. I do the very same thing on dozens of servers and I've never had this issue. The rewrite is internal to Apache. There is no way for Google to know about that. Might it be possible that you are using some old `server.php`-style links internally to your site, rather than the SEO-friendly versions?

Comment: I didn't think of that. I'll check the site links

Comment: Can you first make sure whether Google ins indexing both versions of page?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest/easiest way is to store URL that page should have `/article/58-cute-cat-pictures` and then just check it once page is loaded against [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and then just use [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to send [`301`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).

```
if( $url != $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']){
    $url = build_absolute_url( $url); // For location header
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header("Location: $url");
    exit();
}
```

This way the URLs should be handled just fine.